# Replace unreadable characters from the header of a file in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I got a scenario where I have to read files from a directory. These files contains some special characters at the header when opening it with notepad ++ these characters can be seen as NULLNULL(so on, these characters could be anything but readable text probably some applications header). How can I replace these characters to massage the file and store it in a readable format.

Comment: You can strip them with command `strings`

Comment: You could use perl with regex to filter out all non-alphanumeric characters (and some others, you would have to define what you want to keep).